# Just installed Ubuntu/Ruby, cant create rails project

Tags: ruby, rails, gem

so I've just started using Ubuntu a few days ago, started trying to get an IDE working for Ruby on Rails developement, downloaded/installed everything from scratch. I found out the first version of Ruby I had on here was 1.9.1 so I updated to 2.3.0 and now its throwing this error whenever I try to make a new rails.

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find railties (>= 0) amongst [bundler-unload-1.0.2, did
_you_mean-1.0.0, executable-hooks-1.3.2, gem-wrappers-1.2.7, minitest-5.8.4, minitest-5.8.3, net-telnet-0.1.1, power_assert-0.2
.7, power_assert-0.2.6, rake-10.5.0, rake-10.4.2, rdoc-4.2.2, rubygems-bundler-1.4.4, rvm-1.11.3.9, test-unit-3.1.7, test-unit-
3.1.5] (Gem::LoadError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1231:in `gem'
        from /usr/local/bin/rails:22:in `'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try run:

```
gem install bundler
bundle update
```

or maybe re-install rails:

```
gem install rails
```

If not working you can re-install the rails for your version of ubuntu in this link https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/16.04